# Error handling implemented by IHttpModule doesn't work in IIS6, works in IIS5.1

Tags: error-handling, iis-6, ihttpmodule

I implement common error handling by using IHttpModule. Locally on my machine with WinXP it works like a charm. Once I upload solution on our test server, which is W2003 it doesn't work. Once an error occurs it displays directly in an asp.net error page. It doesn't process using my error module.

Any suggestion most welcome....X.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your custom error is set correctly. I'm guessing your testing locally and getting different behavior than remotely.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error" />
```